# Zapier + MySQL + PythonAnywhere

Tags: mysql, pythonanywhere, zapier

I currently am hosting a MySQL database on PythonAnywhere AKA the cloud. 
I want to connect this account to my Zapier zap through their MySQL integration. But when I put in my account details like so:
https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere/

I just get an error. Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: you may want to show what the error is, and how you are getting that error

Comment: the error is very generic, i believe the problem i am trying to solve here is impossible